# Jquery evenly resize anchor text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to **evenly** increase and then decrease the font size of anchor text inside a paragraph without moving the paragraph text. This way the anchor text will look as if it is coming toward the user and then receding back into its original place. The font-size also appears as if it is growing from the lower left corner as opposed to what I want which is evenly from all sides.

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  <a>[D]</a>I've been workin' on the railroad,
  <a>[G]</a>all the live long <a>[D]</a>day.
  <a>[D]</a>I've been workin' on the railroad,
  just to <a>[E]</a>pass the time a<a>[A]</a>way.
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  color:red;
}
.increase-font {
  font-size: 30px;
  background:#FFF;
}
```

**Jquery/Javascript:**

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = this;
  $(el).addClass('increase-font');
  setTimeout(function(){  
   $(el).removeClass('increase-font');
  },1000);
});
```

**Here is the fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/scooke/ro2tyf6h/

Comment: Could  you please explain what you mean by "not moving the paragraph text"?

Comment: When you click on the anchor in the fiddle, you will see that the paragraph text above,below or to either side moves. Especially if you click on one of the anchors in the middle line. You will see the space between the paragraph lines grow. I am trying to just increase the font size of the anchor without effecting all that is around it.

Comment: I don't think it's that trivial a task. What I would do: 1) give the anchor a container with relative position 2) on click set `visibility:hidden` on the anchor (do NOT use display:none, you still want the element to occupy the space) 3) clone the anchor inside the container 4) give the clone an absolute position. 5) apply the growing/shrinking to the clone - this way the surrounding text would not be affected

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively simple - just wrap the anchor tags in span tags:

```
<p><a><span>[D]</span></a>I've been workin' on the railroad,</p>
<p><a><span>[G]</span></a>all the live long <a><span>[D]</span></a>day.</p>
<p><a><span>[D]</span></a>I've been workin' on the railroad, just to <a><span>[E]</span></a>pass the time a<a><span>[A]</span></a>way.</p>
```

Set the anchor's position to relative (with a margin to give its children spans room), whilst also setting span tags to absolute:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 0px;
  max-width: 0px; 
  margin-right: 25px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Then just swap the jQuery event handler from registering on all anchor tags to all span tags:

```
$('span').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = this;
  $(el).addClass('increase-font');
  setTimeout(function(){  
   $(el).removeClass('increase-font');
  },1000);
})
```

Seeing as absolute elements are removed from the DOM flow, resizing the spans doesn't effect the elements around it. Full code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ro2tyf6h/5/

Comment: That seems to get me most of the way there. Thanks for doing this. I am still unsure of how I can make the text size increase evenly as opposed to from one corner. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd probably use `transform: scale(x)` with a `transform-origin: 50% 50%`, instead of changing font size. I've updated my fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, the anchor texts need to be somewhat independent from the parent. Inserting the anchor text with CSS `:before` or `:after` selectors will solve the problem. See my example and adjust as needed.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = this;
  $(el).addClass('increase-font');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(el).removeClass('increase-font');
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
a {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}
a:before {
  content: "[D]";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center!important;
  width: 100%;
  top: -5px;
}
.increase-font {
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <p> <a></a>I've been workin' on the railroad,</p>
  <p><a></a>all the live long <a></a>day.</p>
  <p><a></a>I've been workin' on the railroad, just to <a></a>pass the time a<a></a>way.</p>
```

**Suggestions:**

1. Restructuring your HTML will be a good start
2. Adding a background to the `:hover` state will help keep it clean
   and distinguishable.